# Jewish Grand Festival

Tags: chagim-holidays

Which are the Jewish grand festival, like christian having Christmas and Muslim having IDD.
Now a day busy in writing a article on different culture festival but not getting any specific data about Jewish, Hope I am not wrong to ask here, if so please feel free to correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define a "grand festival"  The "most important" Jewish holidays are not very festive, and the most festive of holidays are not always important. (Or celebrated by as many Jews)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Judaism, there are three types of "Grand Festivals"

1. We have what are called the "Shalosh Regalim".  These are three holidays where the Jewish people used to all come to Jersulem and are also known as the Pilgramige holidays.

   1. Pesach - Passover (Exodus 12:3-51, 23:15, Leviticus 23:4-8, Numbers 28:16-25)
   2. Shavuot - Pentecost (Ex.23:16, Lev. 23:15-21, Num. 28:26-31)
   3. Sukkot - Feast of Tabernacles (Ex. 23:16, Lev. 23:33-43, 29:12-34)
2. There are also the "Most important" Jewish holidays.  These days are the most solemn, and celebrated by almost all Jews in Israel, even those who don't consider themselves religious.

   1. Yom Kippur -  Day of Atonement (Lev. 23:27-32, Num. 29:7-11)
   2. Rosh Hashana - Jewish New year (Lev. 23:23-25, Num. 29:1-6)
   3. Pesach - Passover (*see above*)
3. There are also the Jewish holidays which are the most "Festive".  These Jewish holidays are sometimes, important, and sometimes not so important. But they have the greatest amount of "fun" associated with them.

   1. Purim - Get dressed up, and give out food and candies, and getting drunk. (Ester 9:26-28)
   2. Hanukah - Lots of fun lights, games, and gelt (gifts of money)
   3. Shmini Etzeret/Simchat Torah (Lev. 23:36, Num. 29:35-38) (the day after the last day of Sukkot) - Lots of dancing, singing, and in some communities, drunkenness.

Comment: +1, it would probably make sense to add 9 Av to the 2nd category, no?

Comment: If I included 9th of Av, I couldn't say "most Jews in Israel".. hard to pick them.

Comment: @Yirmiahu thank you for the edits, but I had them in the order that I did on purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the order then?